# Submitting a paper to a peer-reviewd journal after putting it on medRxiv

Tags: peer-review, arxiv, open-access, preprint

Most COVID-19 related papers(about 2/3) go as pre-prints on arXiv/medRxiv, and so I decided to do the same. Is it still possible to submit the same preprint to a peer-reviewed journal? In such case, are there some rules for bypassing the double-blind review? After submitting, I got an automatic reply from JMIR suggesting a submission to one of their journals. So it seems to be possible, at least.

Comment: I don't think many journals do double blind review these days do they? Certainly every paper I've ever reviewed has had the authors names on it.

Answer (score 2):

Most journals allow this, probably pretty much all of them. If you look at a journal's Guidelines for Authors, they should normally state that this is fine (occasionally it is probably elsewhere but this information should be given on the journal's website). For example, "Statistics in Medicine"'s guidelines say "Statistics in Medicine will consider for review articles previously available as preprints. Authors may also post the submitted version of a manuscript to a preprint server at any time. Authors are requested to update any pre-publication versions with a link to the final published article."

I'm not aware of specific rules for peer review though - I do realise that "double blind" doesn't really mean "double blind" in this case, but what can they do? (Some journals got rid of double blind peer review because authors could be identified in too many cases too easily anyway, this being one of the reasons.)

Comment: "probably pretty much all of them" depends a lot on the field. Medical sciences is lagging a bit, and although there has been a lot of movement into accepting submissions that exist as preprints (even just in the past couple of years), some journals still don't allow it.

Comment: Do you know/can you recommend a journal of reasonable high standing with rapid reviews of Coronavirus AI submissions?